# Printing an int in binary with fixed length

Tags: c++, binary, bitset, std-bitset

I'm overloading `<<` to print custom objects (in this case, instances of a custom class `Vertex`). As part of this, I want to print a given integer in binary. I'd prefer for many reasons to case with `std::bitset` rather than run a for loop, but the problem I'm encountering is that I have a specific size that each binary should be that depends on the instance. Here's the snippet:

```
std::ostream &
operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Vertex& V) {
    os << "(" << std::bitset<4>(V.signature()) << ") :";
    for (int e=2; e<V.degree(); ++e) {
        os << " [" << e << "]=" << V.neighbor(e) << " ";
    }
    return os;
}
```

In place of the `4`, I really want to put a `size_t` that depends on `V`. For example, here's what I tried:

```
std::ostream &
operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Vertex& V) {
    size_t B = V.degree()-1;
    os << "(" << std::bitset<B>(V.signature()) << ") :";
    for (int e=2; e<V.degree(); ++e) {
        os << " [" << e << "]=" << V.neighbor(e) << " ";
    }
    return os;
}
```

The error reads "Non-type template argument is not a constant expression". Is there a way to fix this without hard coding the parameter? It's not something that will be known at compile time.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way of using `std::bitset` with a run-time parameter.

Comment: @vsoftco That's unfortunate. Then is there no way to avoid a for loop?

Comment: probably not. You can write your own custom bitset class for purposing of displaying the bits, but internally you'd still have to perform bit shifts in a loop.

Comment: Boost has some dynamic bitset class.

Comment: Since bitset is template based and therefore not change at runtime you could modify [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/112956/4342498) function

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple function:

```
string bin_format(int_type value, size_t len);
```

which you then write to a stream using

```
out << bin_format(v.signature(), v.degree()-1);
```

Anything beyond that violates the KISS principle and needs to be carefully justified. E.g. if you manage to repeat that so often that the dynamic allocation in `string` causes issues, you could either write a function taking the stream and the parameters and write the single bits to the stream or you could return a proxy with an overloaded `operator<<` where that operator does the formatting and streaming. BTW, you could also turn that function into a template, based on the integer type, so that you can at least put a maximum on the number of bits you need.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no way of using the `std::bitset<>` with a runtime parameter, you should probably write your own "bit-displaying" class/function. Here is an example of such a class that overloads the stream insertion `operator<<`:

```
// Display bits at runtime (cannot use std::bitset<> in this case)

#include <algorithm> // for std::reverse
#include <cstddef>   // for std::size_t
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class disp_bitset
{
    std::size_t _size;
    T _n;
public:
    explicit disp_bitset(std::size_t size, T n): _size(size), _n(n) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const disp_bitset& rhs)
    {
        T tmp = rhs._n;
        std::string aux;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rhs._size; ++i)
        {
            aux += (tmp & 0x01) + '0';
            tmp = tmp >> 1;
        }
        std::reverse(aux.begin(), aux.end());
        return os << aux;
    }
};

int main()
{
    disp_bitset<std::size_t> x(8, 41); // size_t 41 on 8 bits
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << disp_bitset<char>(16, 'a'); // char 'a' on 16 bits
}
```

Comment: This looks like too much overhead with the class, the for loop, and the reverse, but I like the spirit of the idea.

Comment: @PengOne I don't see any way of getting rid of the loop (std::bitset also does this). The `reverse` is not essential though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a total hack, so I'm hoping for something better, but it seems to get the job done for now. Improvements welcome!

```
std::ostream &
operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Vertex& V) {
    std::string bin = std::bitset<16>(V.signature()).to_string();
    bin.erase(bin.begin(),bin.end()-V.degree()+1);
    os << "(" << bin << ") :";
    for (int e=2; e<V.degree(); ++e) {
        os << " [" << e << "]=" << V.neighbor(e) << " ";
    }
    return os;
}
```